# I need to Mask to view only last 4 digits

Tags: db2, cobol

using cobol and db2 please help me to check length of query retrieved data
and mask accordingly to display last 4 digits As an example  if the real account number is 123456789. Then it should display as *****6789. Also if length is 123456 then **3456 like that based on db2 table data retrieval length, also give code for length checking and based on it

Comment: Stackoverlow is not a code writing service. The idea is that __you__ try writing the Cobol code yourself and ask for help *showing your code* when you have an issue.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You might find CREATE MASK useful https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0058564.html

Answer (score 0):

A SQL solution for that as you are using Db2

```
substr('**********',1 , LENGTH('123456789') - 4) || RIGHT('123456789', 4)
```

Just make sure the *** string has the maximum length.

Comment: [`LPAD` would be a better choice](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053529.html), assuming OP's specific version supports it.